# ImportErrors and ModuleNotFoundError for python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, importerror, modulenotfounderror

It seems like my system cannot access modules from other folders. For example, if i set my directory to

```
~/Downloads/principles_of_programming/object-oriented-programming/fibonacci
```

and run

```
pytest tests/test_fibonacci.py
```

I get

```
==================================================== test session starts ===================================================== 
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\Ryan\Downloads\principles_of_programming\object-oriented-programming, configfile: setup.cfg
collected 0 items                                                                                                              

=================================================== no tests ran in 0.05s ==================================================== 
ERROR: file or directory not found: tests/test_fibonacci.py
```

If I change my directory to

```
~/Downloads/principles_of_programming/object-oriented-programming
```

and run the test as above I get

```
==================================================== test session starts ===================================================== 
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\Ryan\Downloads\principles_of_programming\object-oriented-programming, configfile: setup.cfg
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                    

=========================================================== ERRORS =========================================================== 
__________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_fibonacci.py __________________________________________ 
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\Ryan\Downloads\principles_of_programming\object-oriented-programming\tests\test_fibonacci.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests\test_fibonacci.py:1: in <module>
    from fibonacci import fib
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibonacci'
================================================== short test summary info =================================================== 
ERROR tests/test_fibonacci.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
====================================================== 1 error in 0.45s ======================================================
```

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUadf.png)

Comment: How to understand "access modules from other folders"? The file "test_fibonacci.py" is stored in "object-oriented-programming\tests". It needs the path of the file to find the file when the terminal is running.

Comment: SOLVED: Needed to install the packages with python -m pip install -e

Answer (score -1):

Dealing with "import" clauses, Python will first check if it is in its installation folder or whether it is installed package, if it fails, then it searches current working directory, with the relative path considered.

For example `import tests.test_fibonacci` means there is a folder called `tests` in your current working directory, and the script `test_fibonacci.py` is in it and python will run it from the first line to the last line in the namespace "tests.test_fibonacci".

Comment: How should I set my working directory then? Choosing one gives me an ImportError and the other gives me a ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: I suggest copying all the python scriptsyou need to import for a project into one directory.

Comment: That would work, but is there a way to get the import actually working?